# mysql stored procedure, use column name as an argument

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

i have here a table of tapes with 3 fields:

Tapes

```
  TapesID      Title       Qty

     T1     BatDog         3

     T2    UnderCat        2

     T3    IronMouse       1

     T4    Boys Zone       1

     T5    RoboCat         1
```

i want to create a stored procedure that extract and displays specific id’s of tape by entering tape title as argument to the procedure. The procedure should be called list_tspec_id.

can u help me out?im having a hard time with this...

here's my code but it's not right:

```
create procedure tapesid
@columnname varchar
AS
begin
select @columnname from tapes
end 
exec tapesid 'title'
```

Comment: i haven't tried anything, im really stuck with this man..

Comment: What about using [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)?

Comment: Should be `SELECT TapesID WHERE Title = @Title` where @Title should be replaced with the passed argument

Comment: @codingbiz:what do you mean?how can i replace @Title?please bear with me, im just a beginner..

Comment: @fiz:i can't  use prepare statement, it should be procedure..

Comment: It "should be" a stored procedure, because...?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: well then you don't need to pass a column name, but just a value for the where clause? like this:
`CREATE PROCEDURE list_tspec_id(IN t VARCHAR(255))
 BEGIN
  SELECT TapesID FROM tapes WHERE title = t;
 END`

Comment: @michael:because it is the one that is required..im really having a hard time with this..i only knew some basic things in mysql..

Comment: @fiz:when i try to ran it, it has an error, should i include the delimiter?

Comment: well we are struggling here. we don't why you ended up here and every suggestion of how to get out it, you are batting back as unsuitable with no rrason despite admitting to not knowing too much about it. So what's the crack?

Comment: @NeilBryanCasinang: this is just a snippet, you need the delimiters too, like michael posted in his answer, it's essentially the same solution, only that he also selects the other two columns.

Comment: @fiz:ive tried ur code and michael's code below but it shows no result..it keeps sayin '->' , whay this could be?

Comment: The DELIMITER statements change what MySQL expect to mean "process the stuff I've typed so far."  Normally, it's a semicolon, but there are semicolons in the stored procedure, so the first DELIMITER sets $$ as the delimiter instead of a semicolon.  `->` means MySQL is expecting you to keep typing, so you either have made a typo or your delimiter didn't get reset back to a semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tagged this as [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html), so... here's a stored procedure, though it's unclear from your example what you're really wanting it to do or why.

The variables passed into a stored procedure as arguments don't use '@' in front of them.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE list_tspec_id (IN my_title VARCHAR(254))
BEGIN

  SELECT TapesID, Title, Qty FROM Tapes WHERE Title = my_title;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

then...

```
mysql> CALL list_tspec_id('BatDog');
```

Comment: i ran it but it has no output..

call list_tspec_id('BatDog');
mysql>

this is the result..what should be the problem?

Comment: Be sure you reset your delimiter at the end with DELIMITER *space* semicolon... or control-C to break the MySQL connection and reconnect if you get stuck.

Comment: hey can u help with another problem?it is still stored procedure but i need to access 3 tables..